# Difficulty with different kubernetes pods run using kubetctl apply running same container images sharing directories

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am attempting to run two separate pods using the same container image on a cluster by applying a config file. Despite there being no shared or persistent volume when both pods are active the same directory on both pods is updated with created files from the other pod and write access changes suddenly. The container being used is the jupyter-docker-stacks jupyter/minimal-notebook image being pulled directly from dockerhub. These pods running this container is created by applying a manifest. The two pods have different labels and names. A service with a unique name is created for each pod for access.

Do resources for containers persist over time on a cluster like in docker containers? I cannot find something equivalent to a `--rm` flag to be used alongside `kubectl apply`.

Thanks

Comment: As you've described it, the two pods shouldn't share anything.  It'd help if you could include the actual pod YAML in the question, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the pod after the job is completed, you might want to apply `job` instead of `pod`. The idea of `job` in k8s is to launch a pod and do the job, and then the pod get stopped. For more info: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/

Answer (score 0):

`$ kubectl apply -f <fileName>` will create or make some changes in the pod. If you want to delete pod using `apply` you must use `$ kubectl delete -f <fileName>`

About sharing, if you have 2 separate manifest you can specify volumeMounts for each container. For more information please read the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/) depends on your needs.

Also as @Kaizhe Huang advised you can use `Job` if you want to execute something one time or try `initContainers` if you want to install something in POD before main container will be run. More about initContainers [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/).

Answer (score 0):

You could check the dockerfile of your image. See if there are 'VOLUME' claimed. If have, maybe they share the same volume on host. Not sure, but you could check.